# PowerPoint - setting the status bar text

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I'm creating VSTO addins for MS Word/Excel/Powerpoint 2010. In the object model of Word and Excel, there's an `Application.StatusBar` propery exposed, and I can change the status bar's text like this:

```
_app.StatusBar = "My text";
```

However, there is no such property in the object model of PowerPoint. I couldn't find anything similar either.
**How can I change the status bar text in PowerPoint?**

Edit:
My goal is to give the user some kind of feedback when the addin starts doing its thing. Alternative solutions are also welcome!

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't give access to its status bar. A small modeless dialog box used as a progress indicator is another possibility. Or if your add-in has ribbon UI, some kind of change to the ribbon might suffice.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks for confirming this, I will do it some other way then.

Comment: And on the bright side, most PPT users won't be *expecting* status updates on the status bar.  Even MS makes very little use of it, so people tend to pay little or no attention to it. They probably won't beat you up for not using it, then.  ;-)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yeah, I think it's barely noticable in Word / Excel as well. Thanks anyways. If you merge your 2 comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint doesn't give access to its status bar. A small modeless dialog box used as a progress indicator is another possibility. Or if your add-in has ribbon UI, some kind of change to the ribbon might suffice.

And on the bright side, most PPT users won't be expecting status updates on the status bar.

Even MS makes very little use of it, so people tend to pay little or no attention to it. They probably won't mind (or even notice) if you don't use it either.